# Find the centralizer of each element of $ D_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, dihedral-groups

> Consider the dihedral group $D_4$.
>   Find the centralizer of each element of $D_4$.

The elements of $D_4$ are $\{1,r,r^2,r^3,s,sr,sr^2,sr^3\}$

We know that $Z(D_4)=\{1,r^2\}$.

Now centralizer of $r,r^2,r^3=\{1,r,r^2,r^3\}$.

Also $s$ commutes with $sr^2$ hence centralizer of $s,sr^2=\{1,s,sr^2\}$.

Also centralizer of $sr,sr^3=\{1\}$.

Is my computation correct?

Is it true for all even $n$ ,$ s$ commutes with $sr^{\frac{n}{2}}$ and no other element?

Comment: Please do not delete questions after having received an answer.

Comment: @quid;i posted the wrong question

Comment: Alright. But as long as this post makes sense (which it seems it does) you can just as well leave it around. Of course feel free to make a new post for you other questions.

Comment: @quid;okay,would take care of that.

Answer (score 1):

Not correct.

The centralisor of an element is a subgroup of $D_4$. In particular, Lagrange's theorem tells us that the order of a centralisator must divide $8$. Thus, your centralisator for $s$ isn't even a subgroup. Another way to see this is because $s(sr^2)= r^2$ isn't an element in your set. Thus, adjoining the element $r^2$ gives the full centralisator of $s$ (there can't be more elements because Lagrange would imply that $s$ centralises everything and then $s$ lives in the center, which is not the case).

Note also that every element is contained in its own centralisator, thus your answer for the centralisators for $sr, sr^3$ can't be correct either.

Since $r^2$ is in the center, it commutes with everything and thus its centralisator is $D_4$. So this is wrong too.